# How to make IOS Framework encapsulate when user track codes with debug tool?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

I created my own SDK.  I want to make things encapsulated.
I have made a facade class and declared functions as public, only the facade class showed things when user use the SDK.

The problem is, when something Crashed. The debug tool point out to the "internal codes" which I didn't want user to see it (example, secret codes, hash values, etc).

I have tried to seek for answer, but most tutorials only declared about setting function to public, etc. Any idea how to completely encapsulate the codes inside from Xcode Debugging tool?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout strip symbols related options in Xcode project. See screenshoot for reference.

These options allow to extract information regrading classes/methods presented in your SDK. Now if a crash happens - users will see only addresses in the stack trace. You need to keep extracted symbols somewhere - it will help you to analyse reported crashes further - to desymbolicate the stack traces in order to figure out what actually went wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inside xCode settings: `DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING`

[image]

If you want to test this is working in a **release** build, connect lldb and look in the symbol table.

`lldb) image dump symtab -m your_ios_app`

Remember you have to set the **Scheme** for debugging a Release build.

[image: Release debug exec setting]

More reading [here](http://bdunagan.com/2010/05/15/symbolification-shipping-symbols/).